# Saving an Entity without updating relations in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

Is there a proper way to update entities in ef-core without touching the relations? In other words, can I ignore fields on an update?

For example, I have an API where a client can request a Person object. This sent PersonDto will not include any `FinanceData`. If the Client sends the updated Data back, It should write it into the DB, without deleting the `FinanceData` relations.

```cs
public class Person {
  public Guid Id {get,set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public IList<Relation> Relations {get;set;}
  public Adress Adress {get;set;}
  public ICollection<FinanceData> Finances {get;set;}
}
```

I know I could read the object with the Id and write the fields one by to the tracked entity. But this doesn't feel right and I would expect there is a better solution. I tried it with `_context.Entry(person.Finances).State = EntityState.Unchanged;` before `_context.SaveChangesAsync();`  But it throws the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'List<FinanceData>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.
```

Is there a proper way to make this update without reading the entity from the DB before?

Comment: we fetch the tracked object in the db and write field by field from the request object. also normally your request / response object is not the same as your db model

Comment: Will be nice if you show your code for fetching and update the data

Answer (score 0):

I use an approach similar to yours and I can suggest a few things.

First thing is I use the `_context.Entry(person.Finances).State = EntityState.Unchanged;` approach you mentioned but I use `Detached` instead of `Unchanged` for this kind of thing. This will not solve your issue though as you are trying to set the entity state for a collection of entities and not for the related entities hence the error you are experiencing...you would have to do this for each member of the collection.

Another difference I see in my code is that for the collections of related entities I always declare them as `virtual`. Not sure if this is will do you any good. I then handle the inserts or updates of those entities on their own, not passing through the `Person` entity in you case. In your update I would then have the `Finances` property as `null` and I would not have to do anything to it.